# Appending to a dataframe's multi-index and restacking in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How do I append to a dataframe's multi-index and restack by the new index column's sort order?

I have a dataframe with a multi-index `['section_id','last_checkout']` that represents books in a library as follows:

```
                                             book_id   author_id  
section_id    last_checkout
4             2016-04-04 07:01:59.223          1          10
              2016-04-04 07:01:59.223          2          11
              2016-04-04 07:01:59.223          3          12
              2016-04-04 07:01:59.233          4          13
              2016-04-04 07:01:59.247          5          13
              2016-04-04 07:01:59.253          6          14
5             2016-04-04 07:01:59.253          10         15
              2016-04-04 07:01:59.268          11         10
```

so books `1` to `6` are in section `4`. I plan to add another column, `pd.Series({'floor': [1,1,2,1,2,3,4,1]})` to the index:

```
                                                 book_id   author_id  
section_id  floor  last_checkout
4           1      2016-04-04 07:01:59.223          1          10
            1      2016-04-04 07:01:59.223          2          11
            2      2016-04-04 07:01:59.223          3          12
            1      2016-04-04 07:01:59.233          4          13
            2      2016-04-04 07:01:59.247          5          13
            3      2016-04-04 07:01:59.253          6          14
5           4      2016-04-04 07:01:59.253          10         15
            1      2016-04-04 07:01:59.268          11         10
```

After this, I want to stack by rows by floor while maintaining the ordering that already exists:

```
                                                 book_id   author_id  
section_id  floor  last_checkout
4           1      2016-04-04 07:01:59.223          1          10
            1      2016-04-04 07:01:59.223          2          11
            1      2016-04-04 07:01:59.233          4          13
5           1      2016-04-04 07:01:59.268          11         10
4           2      2016-04-04 07:01:59.223          3          12
            2      2016-04-04 07:01:59.247          5          13
            3      2016-04-04 07:01:59.253          6          14
5           4      2016-04-04 07:01:59.253          10         15
```

I thought it should be pretty simple but the API seems unintuitive after I tried various permutations of these unsuccessfully:

```
# Cannot append equal length series to multi-index
#1: df.index = df.index.append(series)

# Underlying mergesort does not 'stack' the groups in original ordering
#2: df['floor'] = series
#3: df.sort_values('floor', ascending=True)
#4: df.sort_values(['floor', 'last_checkout'], ascending=[True,True])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for you.

First the way you are defining your series is quite unorthodox. Best to define the series as:

```
test = pd.Series([1,1,2,1,2,3,4,1],name='floor')
```

then take your multi-index data-frame and reset the index. To "append"/vertically stack a column use 'join' instead of 'append'. so this is how the code should look like

---

```
df = df.reset_index()
floor_series = pd.Series([1,1,2,1,2,3,4,1],name='floor')
df = df.join(test)
df = df.sort('floor')
df = df.set_index(['floor','section_id'])
```